# Live Face Recognition SDKs/Libraries for iOS?

Tags: ios, opencv, sdk, libraries, face-recognition

I want to create a live face recognition app for iOS. I have read about following options:

1. OpenCV
2. Luxand
3. SightHound
4. Kairos

The only thing I want is to make the app free from REST APIs (no dependency on internet). It can be based on any algorithm and use Machine learning to improve its accuracy. I know most of the above mentioned options are per my requirement, but still I am finding them difficult to implement in a standalone iOS app.Is there any good tutorial for live face recognition app or something more helpful to implement such app for iOS. It would be a bonus for me if it can also support Swift. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html
It would be a good start...

Comment: You can also take a look at `CIDetector`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cidetector

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the others but **OpenCV** matches your criteria. 
OpenCV is written in C++ so you can use it with Objective C and then Swift. 
The tricky part is that you will have to implement C++ functions on Objective C.

If you don't know how to do that I'll suggest you to click [here.](http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects)

Other than that, OpenCV is very complete, well documented and with a lot of possibilities.
You can find videos about face recognition using OpenCV so you will not be lost.

I personnaly use it with ARKit for an iOS app able to detect 3D objects.